# Como substituir extensões de arquivos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou aprendendo python no coursera, e me deparei com o seguinte exercício. Minha dúvida refere-se com a forma de alterar as extensões de strings `.hpp` para para `.h` dentro ali da list comprehension:

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]

newfilenames = [ i for i in filenames if _____] 

print(newfilenames) 
# Should be ["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Como você precisa substituir uma extensão por outra você deve trabalhar com fatiamento de strings.

Observe que as extensões que precisas substituir possuem **4 caracteres** que são; `.hpp`. desse modo você precisa percorrer a lista que contém todas as strings, verificando se alguma delas - que vou chama-la de **i** - possui a extensão igual à `.hpp`, ou seja, se o fatiamento da respectiva string do índice **-4** até o final forma a extensão `.hpp`. Em outras palavras...

```
i[-4:] == '.hpp'
```

Caso, alguma dessas extensões seja `.hpp`, devemos substituí-las por `.h`. O que conseguimos com uma concatenação entre a parte da string **SEM** a extensão com a nova extensão `.h`, ou seja:

```
i[:-4] + '.h'
```

Utilizando esta lógica juntamente com **[List Comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)**, podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
newfilenames = [i[:-4] + '.h' if i[-4:] == '.hpp' else i for i in filenames]

print(newfilenames)
```

Dessa forma, obtemos como saída, o seguinte resultado:

```
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']
```

---

Outra forma ágil de resolver esta questão é chamando a função **replace**. Desta forma o código ficaria:

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
newfilenames = [i.replace('.hpp', '.h') for i in filenames]

print(newfilenames)
```

Neste código, o bloco for percorre a lista **filename**, substituindo todas as substrings **.hpp** por **.h**.

Answer (score 0):

Se quer trabalhar com nomes de arquivos, você até poderia manipular as strings diretamente, como indica a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/503491/112052).

Mas também tem a opção de usar um módulo específico para tal, como o [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Assim você pode verificar a extensão do arquivo e mudá-la de acordo:

```
from pathlib import Path

def change_extension(nome_arq):
    path = Path(nome_arq)
    # se a extensão é .hpp, troca por .h e retorna o novo nome
    if path.suffix == '.hpp':
        return path.with_suffix('.h').name
    # senão, retorna o nome sem modificação
    return nome_arq

filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]

newfilenames = [ change_extension(name) for name in filenames ] 
print(newfilenames) # ["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]

# outra opção: aplicar a função a todos os elementos usando map
newfilenames = list(map(change_extension, filenames))
```

Desta forma me parece mais simples do que ficar fatiando strings e trocando pedaços dela.

E a função é facilmente extensível, pois se precisar trocar mais extensões, você pode por exemplo ter um dicionário que mapeia o antes e depois:

```
from pathlib import Path

def change_extension(nome_arq, substituicoes):
    path = Path(nome_arq)
    if path.suffix in substituicoes: # se a extensão deve ser substituída
        return path.with_suffix(substituicoes[path.suffix]).name
    return nome_arq

substituicoes = {
    '.hpp': '.h', # trocar .hpp por .h
    '.cpp': '.c', # trocar .cpp por .c
    '.out': ''    # extensão .out é removida
}
filenames = ["program.cpp", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out", "abc.txt", "def.c"]
newfilenames = [ change_extension(name, substituicoes) for name in filenames ] 
print(newfilenames) # ['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a', 'math.h', 'hpp', 'abc.txt', 'def.c']
```